# Objective function

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to learn how to write objective functions for any problem or real-life action(not mathematical problems) can anyone suggest a good source? On online I am mostly finding objective functions for mathematical problems. Can anyone tell from where can i learn or practice those ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple one: You go to a restaurant, sit down at a table, and want a nice meal.

Define, as precisely as possible, leaving nothing out, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated it